# BodyEditorLoader - error reading file

Tags: java, android, json, libgdx

So I have recently started learning **libgdx** in **Android Studio**. I am using some extensions like **box2d**. To create some nice borders around the object, I am using **Physics Body Editor**. So, as there were many errors in my own code, i have just copied one from here: [Code Sample](https://code.google.com/p/box2d-editor/source/browse/loader-libgdx-demo/src/aurelienribon/bodyeditor/App.java). But still, I keep getting an error on the following line:

```
BodyEditorLoader loader = new BodyEditorLoader(Gdx.files.internal("tankA.json"));
```

The file **tankA.json** is in my assets folder.

Here is my error:

```
02-12 08:27:52.216  13720-13734/com.tynibattles04.game.android E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: GLThread 6581
Process: com.tynibattles04.game.android, PID: 13720
com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxRuntimeException: Error reading file: tankA.json (Internal)
        at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidFileHandle.read(AndroidFileHandle.java:77)
        at com.badlogic.gdx.files.FileHandle.length(FileHandle.java:605)
        at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidFileHandle.length(AndroidFileHandle.java:220)
        at com.badlogic.gdx.files.FileHandle.estimateLength(FileHandle.java:233)
        at com.badlogic.gdx.files.FileHandle.readString(FileHandle.java:198)
        at com.badlogic.gdx.files.FileHandle.readString(FileHandle.java:191)
        at aurelienribon.bodyeditor.BodyEditorLoader.<init>(BodyEditorLoader.java:41)
        at com.tynibattles04.game.TinyBattles.createBottle(TinyBattles.java:127)
        at com.tynibattles04.game.TinyBattles.create(TinyBattles.java:74)
        at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidGraphics.onSurfaceChanged(AndroidGraphics.java:241)
        at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.guardedRun(GLSurfaceView.java:1512)
        at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.run(GLSurfaceView.java:1240)
 Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: tnkA.json
        at android.content.res.AssetManager.openAsset(Native Method)
        at android.content.res.AssetManager.open(AssetManager.java:355)
        at android.content.res.AssetManager.open(AssetManager.java:329)
        at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidFileHandle.read(AndroidFileHandle.java:75)
```

Do you know what could i do with all that?
Thanks in advance!

I have accidentally misspelled **tankA.json** in the error code - thanks to *Angel Angel*. But I still keep getting the same error. Maybe that's be cause something wrong this the **BodyEditorLoader**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the *file name* and the name you use to load, then you say:

```
BodyEditorLoader loader = new BodyEditorLoader(
                          Gdx.files.internal("tankA.json"));
```

But in stack says:

```
com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxRuntimeException: 
                        Error reading file: 
                        tnkA.json (Internal)
```

maybe this is an error in the *file name:*  **tnkA.json**

*note:* maybe in your code use, **tnkA.json** and not **tankA.json** as you think.

hope it helps.